# If then else with variables and update table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to develop an easy routine to update 2 tables from insur database.

The first table is `tarticulo` and it has an `art_existencia` field and I have another table named `Fisico` that has a field called `art_fisico`. In the field `art_existencia` of table `tarticulo`, I have negative and positive integer values, including zero. In the second table, `Fisico`, I always have positive values. I need to develop a routine to update `art_existencia` with the values from `Fisico`, but  I need to do some questions to create a condition.

Example, product A has `tarticulo.art_existencia = 100` and in `Fisico`, product A has `art_fisico = 200`

In this case if `art_existencia` is <= 0, the value have to be `art_fisico`.
but if the value in `art_existencia` is positive (sample product A `art_existencia = 80` and in `art_fisico = 20`), then I need to do leave in `art_existencia = 20` and get the difference value to review the difference in the Kardex module! In the case where `art_fisico` is greater than `art_existencia`, leave the `art_fisico` value but I need the difference between `art_existencia` and `art_fisico`.

Comment: Welcome SO @HECERO. Can you please share with us anything that you might have tried? Also, it makes it way easier for people to help if you provide table examples on input and expected output.

Comment: Also, what is the primary key on both tables mentioned above? how do they relate to each other? is it through production column for example?

Answer (score 0):

Following example might be helpful:

```
declare @tarticulo table (product varchar(100), art_existencia int)
insert into @tarticulo select 'A', 100
insert into @tarticulo select 'B', 200
insert into @tarticulo select 'C', 300
insert into @tarticulo select 'D', -20
insert into @tarticulo select 'E', 0
insert into @tarticulo select 'F', 10

declare @Fisico table (product varchar(100), art_fisico int)
insert into @Fisico select 'A', 10
insert into @Fisico select 'B', 210
insert into @Fisico select 'F', 100
insert into @Fisico select 'C', 30
insert into @Fisico select 'D', 40

--select * from @tarticulo
--select * from @Fisico

select t.product, t.art_existencia-f.art_fisico 'difference (tarticulo-Fisico)'
from @tarticulo t
join @Fisico f on f.product = t.product

update t set art_existencia = case when t.art_existencia < 0 then f.art_fisico when f.art_fisico > t.art_existencia then t.art_existencia else f.art_fisico end
from @tarticulo t
join @Fisico f on f.product = t.product

select product, art_existencia as art_existencia_updated from @tarticulo
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7bda5db9da32f860d2623eaf56baae01)